# Finding a node (JObject) within JArray using JSON.NET library

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using JSON.NET library. I have created few JObjects and added them to a JArray.

```
JArray array = new JArray();

JObject obj = new JObject();
obj.Add(new JProperty("text", "One"));
obj.Add(new JProperty("leaf", false));
array.Add(obj);

obj = new JObject();
obj.Add(new JProperty("text", "Two"));
obj.Add(new JProperty("leaf", false));
array.Add(obj);

obj = new JObject();
obj.Add(new JProperty("text", "Three"));
obj.Add(new JProperty("leaf", true));
array.Add(obj);
```

Now I want to find a JObject who's text (JProperty) is `Two`. How can I find a JObject within a JArray by using a JProperty.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can find it like this:

```
JObject jo = array.Children<JObject>()
    .FirstOrDefault(o => o["text"] != null && o["text"].ToString() == "Two");
```

This will find the first `JObject` in the `JArray` having a property named `text` with a value of `Two`.  If no such `JObject` exists, then `jo` will be null.

Comment: Thanks to your solution, I was able to solve my problem, which is very similar.