# XML to json converter with the tag

Tags: c#, json, xml

I want to convert xml document to json. In xml they define each and every tag. I also want to do like this

XML document:

```
                   gameHistoryMain = new XDocument(
                          new XElement("History",
                             new XElement("userid", playerID),
                             new XElement("gamedetails")
                             ));
```

Here I am confused what json property is suitable?? I tried

```
jsonObject JsonArray JsonProperty
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Import `Json.Net` package from `NuGet` package manager

use `Newtonsoft.Json` reference on your class file

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

The following code snippet helps you to convert XDocument to JSON

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(gameHistoryMain,Formatting.Indented,true);
```

--SJ

Comment: your answer after getting data as xml format then using serializenode i can change as json format.. here i no need of xml conversion. directly i want to change as json format.

Comment: Is it solve your problem? Still do you face any issue??

Comment: Refer this question link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726121/finding-a-node-jobject-within-jarray-using-json-net-library

Comment: Refer this also: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDeclaratively.htm